# ActiveX support for 64 bit application

Tags: c#

We are converting our 32 bit application(.Net Framework 1.1) **to** 64 bit(Framework 2.0).After the conversion the project is building and running successfully except in some places were we are using ActiveX control **iPlotx** and **Slider** . The converted application runs fine when the target platform is 32 bit but in 64 bit mode it is showing class not registered error. Please note that the machine on which i'm testing is 64 bit.

> Error : Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

After some search what i understood is - Since my application is running as 64 bit and since **ActiveX supports only 32 bit** hence this error.

I would like to know if my understanding of the problem is correct and if there is a workaround for this problem **other than letting the application run as 32 bit on a 64 bit machine.**

Comment: A X bit application can only host X bit ActiveX Controls. Is there a compelling reason for using a 64 bit process? Its not inherently "better".  (ActiveX is not itself limited to being 32 bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding isn't quite correct. ActiveX is certainly supported for 64-bit applications, but *only using 64-bit controls*. 32-bit controls don't work in 64-bit applications (and vice versa). If you had 64-bit versions of the controls in question, it should run. Ask your supplier if they have a 64-bit version available.

The workaround if no such version is available is to host the control in a 32-bit process, and shuttle requests back and forth between that process and yours. This gets fairly involved if you have to integrate it into a GUI, however.

Comment: Thank you for the response Jeroen. Any idea if 64 bit versions are available for  iPlotx (iPlotLibrary.ocx) and Microsoft Slider  Control 6.0 (SP6). I tried searching but was unable to find anything useful.

Comment: No, I don't know. If you can't find anything, it's very likely the answer is "no, there is no 64-bit version". This is almost certainly the case for the Slider control, since it's part of the VB 6 common controls library, and VB 6 only comes in a 32-bit edition.